# Помогите вывести ключи из словаря в Python через print

Tags: python-3.x, dict, print

```
a={'k007ao':'Andrey','m010ko':'Ivan','m736yc':'Zhenya','h027ab':'Sveta','a047ch':'Anya'}
for key in a:
   print (key)
```

Comment: `print(*a)`....

Answer (score 0):

Нужно делать так:

```
print(', '.join(a.keys()))
```

Помогло?